# Is there a way to source control Google Stackdriver alerting policies?

Tags: stackdriver

https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/ currently mentions only console based configuration. It would be really helpful if there was a way to define this as a yaml or json, and upload that config to stackdriver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

and thanks for using Google Stackdriver!
Currently there is no way to source control alerting policies. We realize the need and are thinking of ways to improve and add similar abilities.